# Trying to use gridfs but something is not outputting correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs

Hey so I am trying to use gridfs to store profile pictures... I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I am kind of new to this as well.

This is what I got so far, but it seems to be erroring this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'primary' of undefined
    at Stream.GridStore.open (..\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\gridfs\gridstore.js:146:69)
```

This is my code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
var GridStore = require('mongodb').GridStore;
var Step = require('step');


exports.newProfilePicturePost = function(req, res) {
    var db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/test5');
    var fileId = new ObjectId();
    var gridStore = new GridStore(db, fileId, "w", {
        "metadata": {
            category: 'image'
        }, content_type: 'image'});
    gridStore.chunkSize = 1024 * 256;

    gridStore.open(function(err, gridStore) {
     Step(
       function writeData() {
         var group = this.group();

         for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; i += 5000) {
           gridStore.write(new Buffer(5000), group());
         }
       },

       function doneWithWrite() {
         gridStore.close(function(err, result) {
           console.log("File has been written to GridFS");
         });
       }
     )
    });

};
```

Any help or fixes I should make to my code is welcomed, also I am not sure how to specify the collection I want to store the picture in and I want to also add the userId to the picture being saved in the collection for fetching it later.